# Spanning tree and minors

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are finite, undirected graphs with no loops.
If, for every spanning tree $F$ of $G$, there is a spanning tree $F'$ of $H$ such that $F$ is a minor of $F'$, can one conclude that $G$ is a minor of $H$?